# Magento Connect: Extension unable to Install - Magento Community Edition

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-community, magento-connect

I am working on a magento 1.9 e-commerce project tried to install a plugin through magento connect and this is the error i get :

> SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'magento-community'

This occours when i insert the extension key
and this happens when i try to upload the extension package:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
>   Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars
>   Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
>   Invalid stability
>   Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM
>   Invalid channel URL
>   Empty authors section
>   Empty package contents section

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....